# Getting ERROR_RESOURCE_TYPE_NOT_FOUND in ATL application

Tags: c++, atl

Im getting ERROR_RESOURCE_TYPE_NOT_FOUND error when i try and load icon from resources.

```
CComModule module;
...
module.Init(nullptr, instance); //in WinMain
...
HICON appIco = LoadIcon(module.GetResourceInstance(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));
```

ERROR_RESOURCE_TYPE_NOT_FOUND comes from LoadIcon

Comment: So your binary does not have this resource?

Comment: you are right Roman. I forgot too install the graphics library when i re installed Visual studio the other day.